# Recorded script by blaze Meter & browser is showling all cookies but JMeter is not i.e. ai_user & ai_session, how do I get those cookies values?

Tags: session, cookies, jmeter, performance-testing, session-cookies

Browser shows all cookies when we hit home request

[image]

These are the cookies that appear in browser when we execute home page 1st time, but not in Jmeter request

[image]

Its JMeter response that shows cookies

[image]

My issue is when I execute home page in browser it shows all cookies 1st time when we hit request but in JMeter home request don't show up all cookies as shown in picture.

I want cookies values i.e. **ai_user & ai_session**  and pass them to **UserSessionId & AppSessionId** in **HTTP request header**. So how do I get those values? I already user **HTTP CookiesManager** in my script to handle cookies but can't get ai_user & ai_session cookies values.

Answer (score 0):

1. Given you send [the same request in JMeter as in the real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) you should get the same response so double check all the request details like:

   - URL
   - [Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
   - Body
   - etc.
2. Try using clean browser session or at least [private mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)
3. Look at [Set-Cookie header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) for the first request and see if the cookies you're looking for are there. It might be the case that the cookies are being set by [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and as per [JMeter Project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/)

   > JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

   So if this is the case you will need to mimic the JavaScript code logic using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) or just extract the values from the response if they are there using other suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)